# Excel formula for counting the number of rows away from TRUE event in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel table that looks like this;

[image]

The cells in the column `Number of rows away from occurrence` counts the number of rows that are away from a `TRUE` event in `Occurrence` column.

I would like to have a formula for the cells in column `Number of rows away from occurrence`.

I am using Microsoft Excel 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this formula in the 2nd column would work:

```
=IF(A2, 0, SUM(B1, 1))
```

Copy and paste to all rows in that column. The function looks to see if the current row has a TRUE in the first column. If it does, it sets it to zero. Otherwise, it adds 1 to the value in the previous row of the 2nd column.

Comment: Brilliant! I have verified your answer to be correct. Editing your answer to incorporate @ScottCraner's suggestion would be even better.